# xvfb run error in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pyqt4, xvfb

My task is crawling the google search results using headless webkit(PyQt4.QtWebkit) in python.
The module was crawling the results fine using PyQt4.I should have to execute this script in amazon ec2.So,I should have to use [Xvfb](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/xvfb.htm) (no x server in ec2).

At the same time my module has to be executed in a loop.So, It was working fine for some iterations.After some looping module runs into **"xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start"**

How it is supposed to solve?

This is my looping:

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        query_dict["start"] = i * 10
        url = base_url + ue(query_dict)
        flag = True
        while flag:
            parsed_dict = main(url)
            time.sleep(8.4)
            flag = False
    except:
        pass
```

main(url) :

```
def main(url):
    cmd = "xvfb-run python /home/shan/temp/hg_intcen/lib/webpage_scrapper.py"+" "+str(url)
    print "Cmd EXE:"+ cmd
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    result = proc.stdout.readlines()
    print "crawled: ",result[1]
    return result
```

webpage_scrapper will fetch all the html results using pyqt4.
How to avoid the xvfb failing for looping?

Comment: I am using the amazon ec2 server instance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add `--auto-servernum` parameter for `xvfb-run`. Otherwise, it tries to spawn `Xvfb` on the same display (by default `:99`), which will fail if you already have one running.

Answer (score 10):

Run like this,

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 python webpage_scrapper.py http://google.com
```

Comment: I'm suprised this works... you are passing conflicting args: `--auto-servernum` tells it to user a free display, and  ` --server-num=1` tell is use display 1.... use one arg or the other depending on your needs.