# xvfb failed to start in ubuntu

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, webkit, xvfb

I trying to get a screen shot by using the following two tools (something relative to qt, webkit and etc. maybe)

- https://github.com/adamn/python-webkit2png
- http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

when run it on server using xvfb-run following the guide of them, I got the error: Xvfb failed to start

then I searched the situation and find a similar question here

[xvfb run error in ubuntu 11.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805032/xvfb-run-error-in-ubuntu-11-04)

then try to add

```
--auto-servernum --server-num=1
```

now the whole command is:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 -server-args="-screen 0, 640*480*24" python webkit2png.py --url=http://google.com --out=test.png
```

but got another error: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: 187: kill: No such process

how to solve it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works when I remove "-server-args". Try doing that.

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 python webkit2png.py --url=http://google.com --out=test.png
```

This is the command you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

`server-args` option is wrong, in your case it should be :

> --server-args="-screen 0, 640x480x24"