# wkhtmltopdf not handling multiple request at a time (through threads)

Tags: multithreading, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate multiple pdf at same time through threads, below is wkhtmltopdf command

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x680x24" wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver
```

this work perfectly for one request at a time, but it fails when there are multiple request at the same time (multiple threads).
Is there any issue or restriction on number of request handle by wkhtmltopdf ?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer just added `--auto-servernum` in between `xvfb-run  and --server-args` [here is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805032/xvfb-run-error-in-ubuntu-11-04)